# What's the best way to get to Crawl log in SharePoint Online 2013?

Tags: search, sharepoint-online, crawl, office-365, logs

In SPO, Search suddenly stopped working. Can't even locate files from inside document libraries.

Where is the crawl log in SPO?

Comment: Yeah simple question - I thought. So I brows to my SPO-site to find the crawl log for you. But the only thing I can find is the permission to view the crawl log. How stupid is that on a scale? Anyway, you have a great question which I support, and will try to find the answer to if no one else beat me to it. +1 and favorite question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to see the crawl log in SharePoint Online, you need to [create an eDiscovery Site Collection](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/set-up-an-ediscovery-center-in-sharepoint-online-HA104042284.aspx).

[image]

When the eDiscovery SC is created, create a case and add a souce. Finally run queries exporting content to your source case.

> 1. In the eDiscovery Center, open the case that you want to add a source to.
> 2. Click eDiscovery Sets.
> 3. Type a name for the eDiscovery Set, such as Executive Correspondence.
> 4. Next to Sources, click Add & Manage Sources.
> 5. In the dialog box that appears, under Mailboxes, type the account names or e-mail addresses for the Exchange mailboxes T
> 6. Under Locations, type the URL or file share address for the content you want to use as the source. Any content you include must be indexed by search.
> 7. Click Save.
> 8. In the box under Filter, type any keywords you want to use to narrow down the source.
> 9. To narrow down content by a date range, enter the Start Date and End Date.
> 10. To limit results to the author of a document or list item, or to a specific sender of e-mail messages, type the names or e-mail addresses in the Author/Sender box.
> 11. To limit results to a specific Exchange domain, type its name in the Domain box.
> 12. Click the Apply Filter button.
> 13. Click Enable In-Place hold.
> 14. To verify that you’ve selected the right content, click Preview Results.
> 15. Click Save.

Source: [Plan and manage eDiscovery cases](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/plan-and-manage-ediscovery-cases-HA102893857.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint PnP Powershell contains a command to get crawl log : [Get-PnPSearchCrawlLog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpsearchcrawllog?view=sharepoint-ps).

You can get the crawl log for a specific url prefix (for example):

```
import-module sharepointpnppowershellonline

Connect-PnPOnline https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/somecollection 

Get-PnPSearchCrawlLog -Filter "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/somecollection/Shared Documents"
```

Will return (date are in french in my case):

```
Url             : https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/somecollection/Shared Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx
CrawlTime       : 22/01/2020 09:17:24
ItemTime        : 01/01/0001 00:00:00
LogLevel        : Success
Status          : 
ItemId          : 656269
ContentSourceId : 1

Url             : https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/somecollection/Shared Documents/doc1.docx
CrawlTime       : 21/01/2020 15:22:58
ItemTime        : 09/11/2019 00:43:15
LogLevel        : Success
Status          : 
ItemId          : 1054666
ContentSourceId : 1

Url             : https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/somecollection/Shared Documents/doc2.docx
CrawlTime       : 21/01/2020 14:55:41
ItemTime        : 21/01/2020 17:10:43
LogLevel        : Success
Status          : 
ItemId          : 1239818
ContentSourceId : 1
```